Find a line parallel to a given line with a specific offset
I hope you are well.
I am writing a game with Python using PyQt6.
I am having trouble finding a parallel line with a specific offset.
Let's say we have the situation below.
Image
there is a line (red line) in the game and an offset (e.g. 2) and we want the parallel line with that offset (orange line).
my solution is:

pick a point (red point) on the given line (red line).
find a perpendicular line (blue line) to the given line (red line) that goes through the point (red point) found in step 1.
imagine a circle (green circle) on the point (red point) with the radius of the given offset.
pick one of the intersections (orange point) of the circle (green circle) and the perpendicular line (blue line).
draw a line (orange line) with the slope of the given line (red line) that goes through the point (orange point) found in 4th step.

Is there any easier and faster(in terms of running code) way to find the orange line?
Is my way to find the orange line correct?
I also have a problem with 4th step of this algorithm. how can I find the intersection of a line and a circle?
I searched about it and saw this but it did not help.

If your line is represented in parametric form as
\begin{align}
x &= x_0 + lt \\
y &= y_0 + mt
\end{align}
and $d$ is the required distance between the two lines, then a unit vector orthogonal to the lines is
$$
\left(-\frac{m}{\sqrt{l^2+m^2}},\frac{l}{\sqrt{l^2+m^2}}\right)
$$
and so a point of the offset line is
$$
\left(x_0 - d \frac{m}{\sqrt{l^2+m^2}}, y_0 + d \frac{l}{\sqrt{l^2+m^2}}\right)
$$
Finally, the parametric equations of the offset line is
\begin{align}
x &= x_0 - d \frac{m}{\sqrt{l^2+m^2}} + lt \\
y &= y_0 + d \frac{l}{\sqrt{l^2+m^2}} + mt
\end{align}
For the other offset line (there are two) simply change the sign of $d$.

If working with explit line equation rather than parametric equation, with equation $y = m(x-x_1) + y_1$, then the offset line is
$$
y = m(x-x_2)+y_2
$$
where
\begin{align}
x_2 = x_1 - d\frac{m}{\sqrt{1+m^2}} \\
y_2 = y_1 + d\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}} 
\end{align}

thanks for your answer and sorry I think this is a stupid question but I do not know what l and t are.
my line comes from two points. p1=(x1,y1), p2=(x2,y2) and the m (slope of the line) = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) and the line equation is y=m(x-x1)+y1. am I right? So what are l and t?

@negaramiri you didn't say how do you represent line equation (there are many ways). I added some more text to my answer at the end to cover your request

Thanks a lot the problem is solved
